# What film or show has a scene with Loki impersonating either Hydra, Red Skull or Nazis?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, loki, hydra

I recall a scene where Nazis, Red Skull, or Hydra members are in the same place an object is found, and they all die. The last man standing gives the hint or totally reveals that he was Loki. I don't know why, but I got the impression that Loki was pulling the strings the whole time to his own ends.

Where is this scene from? Agents of Shield, Marvel Cinematic Universe, etc...?

Comment: Doesn't sound like it's from the MCU.

Comment: Scene from a movie or a tv show, do you mean?

Comment: I thought it was in cpatain america or on of the several post credit scenes but i just can not find anything on the internet so I'd have to watch the movies all over agin to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may have a couple facts mixed up but this should be the scene in Captain America when "Red Skull" walks over to the relief sculpture of Ygrassil and immediately pushes the snake's eye on the third root (Midgard). A box pops out, and "Red Skull" opens it looking at the Tesseract. The tower keeper warns him that "that is not for the eyes of mortal men." Red Skull is not affected, which is a little hint.

[image: Red Skull & The Tesseract]

"Red Skull" then shoots the tower keeper.

[Here is the movie clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B6J61GLQeso), see if it fits what you're thinking of. Your description is like a mix-mash of Indiana Jones and Captain America, nothing else comes to mind.